# Did uiautomatorviewer replace hierarchyviewer in Android Device Monitor?

Tags: android-studio, android-uiautomator, hierarchyviewer

I went to use hierarchyviewer and recieved the following message:

"The standalone version of hieararchyviewer is deprecated.
Please use Android Device Monitor (tools/monitor) instead."

So, I started up Android Device Monitor in Android Studio and could only find

"Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator"

and it launches uiautomatorviewer in the Device Monitor...

Does anyone know if this means Google is intending to replace hierarchyviewer with uiautomatorviewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use the hierarchyviewer in combination with monkeyrunner to do UI testing for android devices. Unfortunately, monkeyrunner was slow and limited and the tests were brittle.

I see the uiautomator as the better tool for inspecting UI elements. It has more powerful methods to identify UI objects and interact with them.
You no longer need to place sleep commands in your script. Just wait for a specific element. You can wait for an element to appear or disappear.

You can have watchers which run in case an UI object is not found. This can be helpful when handling pop-ups and error messages.

Here's a link to a tutorial.
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

I did not see any official statement that says one replaces the other, but I think upgrading to uiautomator is the sensible thing to do. Hierarchyviewer and monkeyrunner are deprecated after all.

Comment: Thanks Gabe...youre my new favorite Overflower

Comment: Where does it say monkeyrunner is deprecated? At the time of writing there is a link at the bottom of this page that points to monkeyrunner. No mention of it being deprecated. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html There's an up vote in it if you can tell me.

Comment: @MichaelVescovo I meant to say that uiautomator surpasses the monkeyrunner. In my opinion, monkeyrunner was way behind the newer api, so I stopped using it. If it makes you feel any better, it was a poor choice of words from my part.

Comment: ok fair enough. It seems the main downside of uiautomator is the minapi level. I have an app that is lower than that. But for newer stuff I'm gonna use uiautomator together with espresso. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

To start the Hierarchy Viewer from Android Studio:

1. Start Android Device Monitor
2. Click the **Open Perspectives** icon  and select **Hierarchy View**.

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]